# Concatenating multiple (up to 24) fields, ordering the resulting string alphabetically

Tags: sql, sql-server, analytics

For context and in case it informs a solution: I work with health data as an analyst. I do not have full DBA rights, I have very limited permissions beyond querying the data although I can create tables and views if I need to in my own schema. The data is stored in SQL Server 2008 although I query it using SSMS 2016 (I know that some functions don't work due to it being in 2008 - and upgrading it isn't anything I have control over!).

The problem: I am looking at a particular set of hospital admissions for patients who have been admitted repeatedly in a year and trying to identify if they share a set of characteristics by using the diagnosis codes in their admission records. A record may have up to 24 diagnosis codes present, but may have as few as one. The admissions sit in a single table called SEM_IP and look similar to this:

```
DW_ID       Diag_1  Diag_2  Diag_3  Diag_4  Diag_5  Diag_6  Diag_7  Diag_8  Diag_9  Diag_10 Diag_11 Diag_12 Diag_13 Diag_14 Diag_15 Diag_16 Diag_17 Diag_18 Diag_19 Diag_20 Diag_21 Diag_22 Diag_23 Diag_24
1275727882  M8697   B957    L031    G473    E669    N40X    M543    I10X    K589    K449    F419    E139    M821    J449    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
1275709370  S8260   W199    J47X    R042    F019    I10X    E119    E780    M819    R296    R13X    R470    G819    I692    D649    R15X    R32X    M169    Z921    Z867    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
1275793044  E115    L97X    L089    B956    U820    I743    N390    G318    F028    K590    I259    I10X    I489    I361    I252    I272    H919    E039    E669    F329    R32X    F171    Z966    Z867
1275787444  I214    I500    I634    I482    N179    Y544    G519    I10X    E119    M199    F329    E669    E780    K269    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
1275788137  K920    R040    I859    F102    K709    F329    E119    K529    I259    Z915    Z922    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
1275725205  F058    G309    F009    N179    K590    R470    H109    I489    M7979   I10X    E039    F329    Z867    I639    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
1275744643  F103    F103    F102    F100    M2556   Z590    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

And as I am only interested in a subset of these diagnosis codes, I've joined to a filtered reference table and my data now looks like this:

```
 DW_ID      Diag_1  Diag_2  Diag_3  Diag_4  Diag_5  Diag_6  Diag_7  Diag_8  Diag_9  Diag_10 Diag_11 Diag_12 Diag_13 Diag_14 Diag_15 Diag_16 Diag_17 Diag_18 Diag_19 Diag_20 Diag_21 Diag_22 Diag_23 Diag_24
1275727882  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    F419    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
1275709370  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    F019    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
1275793044  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    F028    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    F329    NULL    F171    NULL    NULL
1275787444  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    F329    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
1275788137  NULL    NULL    NULL    F102    NULL    F329    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
1275725205  F058    NULL    F009    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    F329    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
1275744643  F103    F103    F102    F100    NULL    Z590    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

What I want is to put all of the relevant codes into one column and sort them in order, with the results looking something like this:

```
DW_ID       Combined
1275727882  F419
1275709370  F019
1275793044  F028,F171,F329
1275787444  F329
1275788137  F102,F329,
1275725205  F009,F058,F329
1275744643  F100,F102,F103,F103,Z590
```

I've seen a few posts on this but most look at only a couple of columns, at the most 4. I haven't seen anything that will also remove the nulls from the string as most are about combining two fields that definitely do contain data.

Is it possible to acheive the results above given the amount of columns involved and the version of SQL Server? Thank you in advance!

Comment: OUCH!!! I know you didn't write but goodness that table design is horrible. I would consider writing a view that normalizes that nightmare. Then you can go through the exercise of denormalizing it in a different horrible way like you you desire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to UNPIVOT your data first

```
SELECT UP.DW_ID, UP.Diag
FROM
(
  SELECT DW_ID  , Diag_1, Diag_2, Diag_3, Diag_4, Diag_5, Diag_6, Diag_7, Diag_8, Diag_9, Diag_10
                , Diag_11, Diag_12, Diag_13, Diag_14, Diag_15, Diag_16, Diag_17, Diag_18, Diag_19
                , Diag_20, Diag_21, Diag_22, Diag_23, Diag_24
  FROM dbo.Table1
) AS T
UNPIVOT 
(
  Diag FOR Diags IN (    Diag_1, Diag_2, Diag_3, Diag_4, Diag_5, Diag_6, Diag_7, Diag_8, Diag_9, Diag_10
                        ,Diag_11, Diag_12, Diag_13, Diag_14, Diag_15, Diag_16, Diag_17, Diag_18, Diag_19
                        ,Diag_20, Diag_21, Diag_22, Diag_23, Diag_24
                    )
) AS UP
```

with gives this - note the missing NULL values

```
DW_ID       Diag
1275727882  F419
1275709370  F019
1275793044  F028
1275793044  F329
1275793044  F171
1275787444  F329
1275788137  F102
1275788137  F329
1275725205  F058
1275725205  F009
1275725205  F329
1275744643  F103
1275744643  F103
1275744643  F102
1275744643  F100
1275744643  Z590
```

Then using STUFF and XML you can then create a CSV list.

Here's the [full solution in SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/e656f/1)

Answer (score 0):

I think your best course of action would be to unpivot your data (using the `UNPIVOT` operator, then sorting, and then concatenating the data (grouping on `DW_ID`). Part of the problem is that SQL Server 2008 doesn't have a nice aggregate string concatenation function so you might have to use a hack to accomplish this.

First things first, let's get the data unpivoted and sorted:

```
SELECT DW_ID, Diag_col, Diag_code FROM (
    SELECT * FROM SEM_IP // your table
) UNPIVOT (
    Diag_code FOR Diag_col IN
      ( Diag_1, Diag_2, Diag_3, Diag_4, Diag_5, Diag_6, Diag_7, Diag_8
      , Diag_9, Diag_10, Diag_11, Diag_12, Diag_13, Diag_14, Diag_15, Diag_16
      , Diag_17, Diag_18, Diag_19, Diag_20, Diag_21, Diag_22, Diag_23, Diag_24 )
) ORDER BY Diag_code;
```

This will give us the diagnostic codes in alphabetical order - there will be a number of rows for each value of `DW_ID` equal to the number of non-null diagnostic codes.

Now SQL Server is not my area of expertise but there are some methods of string aggregation in SQL Server 2008. For example, you might try:

```
WITH sd ( DW_ID, Diag_col, Diag_code ) AS (
    SELECT DW_ID, Diag_col, Diag_code FROM (
        SELECT * FROM SEM_IP // your table
    ) UNPIVOT (
        Diag_code FOR Diag_col IN
          ( Diag_1, Diag_2, Diag_3, Diag_4, Diag_5, Diag_6, Diag_7, Diag_8
          , Diag_9, Diag_10, Diag_11, Diag_12, Diag_13, Diag_14, Diag_15, Diag_16
          , Diag_17, Diag_18, Diag_19, Diag_20, Diag_21, Diag_22, Diag_23, Diag_24 )
    )
)
SELECT DISTINCT DW_ID
     , SUBSTRING(
       ( SELECT ',' + Diag_code AS [text()]
           FROM sd
          WHERE sd.DW_ID = T.DW_ID
          ORDER BY sd.Diag_code
            FOR XML PATH('')
       ), 2, 200 ) AS Combined
  FROM sd AS T;
```

This code was taken from [HERE](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/a6ed7e8c-472d-4be8-887c-d81aa110539d/string-aggregate-concatenation?forum=transactsql) and adapted. The second parameter of `SUBSTRING()`, `2`, is so the final string `Combined` does not start with a comma; the third parameter, `200` is the maximum length of the string (which I estimated based on the number of columns you have and their length).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Very similar to the other answer, both seem to be doing the same job albeit ever so slightly differently. Thank you for taking the time out to help me!